Autoref, theorem, definition
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\autoref{def:definition1}
\autoref{thm:theorem1}
\end{document}


Question: Why \autoref{thm:theorem1} works but \autoref{definition} doesn't work?

You get
Package hyperref Warning: No autoref name for `definition' on input line 18.

You need to provide the name, but also define the environments after loading hyperref.
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{theorem} % <--- obsolete
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\providecommand{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\autoref{def:definition1}
\autoref{thm:theorem1}

\end{document}

Beware that theorem is obsolete; use amsthm (my preferred one) or ntheorem.
However, cleveref is better.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\cref{def:definition1}
\cref{thm:theorem1}

\Cref{def:definition1}
\Cref{thm:theorem1}

\end{document}


You can modify the label used by cleveref, that's based on the environment's name, with \crefname.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\crefname{definition}{definición}{definiciones}
\Crefname{definition}{Definición}{Definiciones}


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\cref{def:definition1}
\cref{thm:theorem1}

\Cref{def:definition1}
\Cref{thm:theorem1}

\end{document}



Thanks. Another question: If I have \newtheorem{definition}{Definición}.
Why \Cref{def:definition1} doesn't appear as Definición 1? (only appears as Definition 1, and, I want this in spanish)

@eraldcoil The label used by cleveref is based on the environment's name. See the edit.

hyperref knows only a limited number of elements. Additional elements can be added:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\autoref{def:definition1}
\autoref{thm:theorem1}
\end{document}


But I would recommend to use package zref-clever:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\zcref[S]{def:definition1}
and \zcref{thm:theorem1}
\end{document}

because it supports, e.g., start sentence (with option [S] and inner sentence form):

and it can be perfectly combined with zref-vario:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-vario}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\zvref[S]{def:definition1} % automatically with page reference if the page is not this one
and \zcref{thm:theorem1} \zvpageref{thm:theorem1}.

\clearpage

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\end{document}


Both also work with several other languages using babel, e.g.:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-vario}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definición}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:theorem1}
\end{theorem}

\zvref[S]{def:definition1} y \zcref{thm:theorem1} \zvpageref{thm:theorem1}.

\clearpage

\begin{definition}\label{def:definition1}
\end{definition}

\end{document}


If you need to redefine the terms, please see the zref-clever user manual, section 10, “Internationalization”.
